# Iterate an ArrayList to count by object attribute

Tags: java, arraylist, enums, enumeration

I have an `ArrayList` of products already initialized. The `Product` constructor is:

```
public Product(String number, String type, double rentalDeposit, double rentalPrice, double lateFee, double buyPrice, int maxDuration)
```

The `type` is determined by an enumeration:

```
protected enum productType {Basket, BabySeat, Helmet, Headlight, Bell};
```

I pass in the `type` using the `toString` method for the enumeration. I need to iterate through the `ArrayList<Product>` (given by `shop.getInventory()`) that I have and count how many of each `type` there are, i.e. how many are of `type` `Basket`, `BabySeat`, `Helmet`, etc.

The `Product` class has a `getType()` method that returns a string.

```
for (Product.productType product : Product.productType.values()) {
    int occurences = Collections.frequency(shop.getInventory(), product.toString());
}
```

I have tried using `Collections.frequency`, but it keeps returning `0` and I'm not sure why.

Is there another way to iterate through and find this amount without using a ton of `if` statements?

Comment: Try replacing: `shop.getInventory()` with: `shop.getInventory().stream().map(product -> `product.productType`).collect(Collectors.toList())`  (and get rid of the for-loop - it's not needed).

Answer (score 0):

`shop.getInventory()` I'll assume has the type `Collection<Product>`. You can either define product such that `.equals(Product)` will check equality against the Product's internal type, or even more simply, `shop.getInventory().stream().filter(item -> product.toString().equals(item.getType())).count()`. (replace `item.getType()` with however you extract the type field from Product, like maybe `item.type` etc).

Answer (score 0):

A simple method of counting items in a list that correspond to some condition is to use `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.counting`. Something like the following:

```
Map<ProductType,Long> counts = products.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Product::getType, counting()));
```

If you're not familiar with streams, this statement can be read as 'turn the list into a stream of products, group the products by product type then count each of those groups creating a map from the type to the count.'